# Facebook : how to if my app is running inside facebook canvas using javascript

Tags: facebook

I want to know whether my app is running in facebook canvas using javascript

please help I dont find any answer online
Thanks

Comment: Not possible. You can check whether it runs inside any kind of (i)frame, but you won’t know on which domain. Canvas and Page Tab apps get a signed_request parameter POSTed to them on initial load into the iframe, that can be used to verify this - but with client-side JS you have no access to POST data, that check needs to be performed server-side.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks Bro for you comment